# Windows Phone 8 input keyboard

Tags: c#-4.0, windows-phone-8, inputscope

I have form of adding members in phone application page,
in that form, one field is ZIP CODE,
so how do I get keyboard of numbers on text changed event?
thanks!!

Comment: What do you mean when you said "keyboard of numbeR"? The index of keyboard who user clicked?

Comment: @MatDev8 I meant to say, if user click on that keyboard, NUMBERED keyboard should be displayed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Check with this InputScope, Refer [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh393998%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

```
 <TextBox Name="txtZipCode" >
        <TextBox.InputScope>
            <InputScope>
                <InputScopeName NameValue="Number" />
            </InputScope>
        </TextBox.InputScope>
    </TextBox>
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer given above in a single line could be

```
<TextBox Name="txtZipCode" InputScope="Number"/>
```